# Naming conventions for a project containg only WCF ServiceReferences?

Tags: wcf, design-patterns, architectural-patterns

Let's say we have a back-end that needs to talk to N external systems using some kind of Web Services.

What I do is: Create a separate project and generate there the proxy classes (using the service's WSDL in the WCF Service Reference dialog).

About the project name suffix:

I firstly though XxAdapter. But then, I started creating classes with additional logic like CircuitBreakers so I ended up with XxAgent (from ServiceAgent).

What should be the "correct" suffix for the name of such projects.

Comment: There's no "correct" or right answer - you need to define that for yourself. The client-side code is often called "proxy" - so that might be one option. Or just something like "client". Take your pick, stick with it - there's no right or wrong or no "Microsoft recommended standard way" of naming those...

Comment: I agree with you. I go with XxAgent.

Comment: xxAgent is fine, or maybe xxClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate suffix is **"Proxies"** because of several reasons:

1. Your component contains all the web service proxy classes.
2. In case that you want to make calls to several service proxies transparent, you can create a new class named **MyLocalProxy**, and perform the action

   public class MyServiceProxy
       {
           public void DoSomething()
           {
               var serviceProxy1 = new ServiceProxy1();
                serviceProxy1.DoOneThing();

   ```
           var serviceProxy2 = new ServiceProxy2();

           serviceProxy2.DoAnotherThing();
       }
   }
   ```

The additional class helps you to not depend on concrete service proxies, so you can interchange them as you wish.

Cheers.